# "Encountered two children with the same key, `[object Object]`."

Tags: react-native, express, expo

I tried making a category filter for my ecommerce app but it keeps giving me this error. I have not connected my app to a database and i am using a json file. I dont have dublicate id's in my json files.

[this is my products json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7JBm.png)

[This is my categories json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACOo1.png)

This is my CategoryFilter.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
    import { ListItem, Badge, Text } from 'native-base';
    
    const CategoryFilter = (props) => {
    
        return(
            <ScrollView
                bounces={true}
                horizontal={true}
                style={{ backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2" }}
            >
                <ListItem style={{ margin: 0, padding: 0, borderRadius: 0 }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        key={1}
                        onPress={() => {
                            props.categoryFilter('all'), props.setActive(-1)
                        }}
                    >
                        <Badge
                            style={[styles.center, {margin: 5},
                                props.active == -1 ? styles.active : styles.inactive
                            ]}
                        >
                            <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>All</Text>
                        </Badge>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    {props.categories.map((item) => (
                          <TouchableOpacity
                          key={item._id}
                          onPress={() => {
                              props.categoryFilter(item._id), 
                              props.setActive(props.categories.indexOf(item))
                          }}
                      >
                          <Badge
                              style={[styles.center, 
                                {margin: 5},
                                props.active == props.categories.indexOf(item) ? styles.active : styles.inactive
                              ]}
                          >
                              <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>{item.name}</Text>
                          </Badge>
                      </TouchableOpacity> 
                     ))}
                </ListItem>
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        center: {
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
        },
        active: {
            backgroundColor: '#03bafc'
        },
        inactive: {
            backgroundColor: '#a0e1eb'
        }
    })
    
    export default CategoryFilter;
```

This is my ProductList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

import ProductCard from './ProductCard'

var { width } = Dimensions.get("window");

const ProductList = (props) => {
    const { item } = props;
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity 
        style={{ width: '50%' }}
        onPress={() => 
            props.navigation.navigate("Product Detail", { item: item})
        }
        >
            <View style={{ width: width / 2, 
                backgroundColor: 'gainsboro'}}
        >
            <ProductCard {...item} />
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

export default ProductList;
```

This is my ProductContainer.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator,Dimensions, FlatList, ScrollView} from 'react-native'
import { Container, Header, Icon, Item, Input, Text } from 'native-base';

import ProductList from './ProductList'
import SearchedProduct from "./SearchedProducts";
import Banner from '../../Shared/Banner';
import CategoryFilter from './CategoryFilter';

var { height } = Dimensions.get('window')

const data = require('../../assets/data/products.json');
const productCategories = require('../../assets/data/categories.json');

const ProductContainer = () => {

    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [productsFiltered, setProductsFiltered] = useState([]);
    const [focus, setFocus] = useState();
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
    const [productsCtg, setProductsCtg] = useState([]);
    const [active, setActive] = useState();
    const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setProducts(data);
        setProductsFiltered(data);
        setFocus(false);
        setCategories(productCategories);
        setProductsCtg(data);
        setActive(-1);
        setInitialState(data);

        return () => {
            setProducts([])
            setProductsFiltered([])
            setFocus([])
            setCategories([])
            setActive()
            setInitialState()
        }
    }, [])

    const searchProduct = (text) => {
        setProductsFiltered(
            products.filter((i) => i.name.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()))
        );
    };

    const openList = () => {
        setFocus(true);
      };
    
      const onBlur = () => {
        setFocus(false);
      };

        // Categories
        const changeCtg = (ctg) => {
            {
            ctg === "all"
                ? [setProductsCtg(initialState), setActive(true)]
                : [
                    setProductsCtg(
                    products.filter((i) => i.category._$oid === ctg),
                    setActive(true)
                    ),
                ];
            }
        }

    return (
        <Container>
        <Header searchBar rounded>
        <Item>
            <Icon name="ios-search" />
            <Input
                placeholder="Search"
                onFocus={openList}
                onChangeText={(text) => searchProduct(text)}/>
                {focus == true ? (
                    <Icon onPress={onBlur} name='ios-close'/>
                ): null}
        </Item>
        </Header>
        {focus == true ? (
        <SearchedProduct
            productsFiltered={productsFiltered} />
        ) : (
            <ScrollView>

                <View>
                    <View>
                        <Banner/>
                    </View>
                    <View>

                        <CategoryFilter
                            categories={categories}
                            categoryFilter={changeCtg}
                            productsCtg={productsCtg}
                            active={active}
                            setActive={setActive}
                        />

                    </View>
                    {productsCtg.length > 0 ? (
                        <View style={styles.listContainer}>
                            {productsCtg.map((item) => {
                                return(
                                    <ProductList
                                        key={item._id.$oid}
                                        item={item}
                                    />
                                )
                            })}
                        </View>
                    ): (
                        <View style={[styles.center, {height: '40%'}]}>
                            <Text>No Products Found.</Text>
                        </View>
                    )}

                </View>

            </ScrollView>
            
        
        )}
        
        </Container>
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flexWrap: "wrap",
      backgroundColor: "gainsboro",
    },
    listContainer: {
      height: height,
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: "row",
      alignItems: "flex-start",
      flexWrap: "wrap",
      backgroundColor: "gainsboro",
    },
    center: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
  });
export default ProductContainer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
key={item._id}
```

Your ids are objects, and React actually expects keys to be strings, and if not will try to coerce them.

What you're seeing here with `[object Object]` is the result of coercing a plain javascript object to a string - and all your ids actually end up coercing to the exact same string.

You would need to either have your ids define their own `toString()` method returning their proper string representation - or simply index the property that returns it if you have one. It seems you do have one at $oid.

```
key={item._id.$oid}
```

Comment: Thank you so much man! This was my first question in stack overflow and didn't think i'd get any help back. Much appreciated!